# Get instance id of electron app installation

Tags: node.js, firebase, electron

I am working on a software built on electron. I would like to know the instance id of each installation of the application. I want something similar to Firebase.instanceId which is used for android.

Similar conditions like firebase instance id:

> Instance ID is stable except when:
>
> - App deletes Instance ID
> - App is restored on a new device
> - User uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - User clears app data